# The __init__() method gets overridden even though I used super(). Why?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

As in the title I initiated the super class `__init__` method in the inheriting class `__init__` method but it still gets overriden, or at least I think it does. I want the self.x = x to work in the inheriting class too.

```py
class Abs(ABC):
    def __init__(self, x: int = 1, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Con(Abs):
    def __init__(self, x: int = 1, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def foo(self):
        print(self.x)

obj = Con(x=4)
obj.foo() # <---- this here returns 1 instead of 4
```

Comment: Your question is really not clear. What is wrong here? Anyway, your init methods are both identical; there isn't any point at all having the one in Con.

Comment: Could you give an example of the behavior that is not working (e.g., from the python terminal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're not passing `x` on in your super call. It should be:

```
def __init__(self, x: int = 1, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(x, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, note that this method is *completely pointless*. You should only override a method if you want to do something different from the superclass version. In this case you don't; you should remove the method completely from Con.